# Javascript - Use a function with?

Tags: javascript

This code is working but I have the hunch it is not proper javascript.

```
function adjustForiOsClients() {
  if (!isIos) {
    return;
  }
  //trigger adjustements based on positive detection
  enableMobileWebAppIos();
}


//supporting funcitons
function isIos() {
  if (os_name === "iOS") {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Indeed, the function is: `isIos()` , but when I call it I use `if (!isIos)` instead of `if ( !isIos() )`, which seems strange as I should use the brackets to refer to isIos as a function, shouldn't I?

I am using `if (!isIos)` because `if (!isIos())` is not working : indeed I tested on iOS device and the function enableMobileWebAppIos() never gets executed when I use what would seem more proper `if (!isIos())` 
      } . Indeed isIos() sends "undefined"

Comment: What is `gon`? Please add complete/relevant code.

Comment: removed it has no value here. os_name is the os (ios/adnroid) name I am getting form the client

Comment: Outside the `if` of `isIos` you should return `false`

Comment: Or even better `function isIos() { return os_name === "iOS" }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isIos` refers to the function itself as value; `isIos()` ***calls*** the function and returns its result. The check `!isIos` is pretty nonsensical since it's always the same (*falsey*, since any function object is *truthy*) as long as `isIos` refers to the same thing (a function).